# Xcode: Permissions denied upon changing Bundle ID

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

Trying to change Bundle IDs for an Xcode project (iCloud is enabled) and I'm getting a "Could not launch app, permission denied" immediately after changing the Bundle Identifier within Xcode. Prior to changing it, it works totally fine. Provisioning profiles appear to be fine, as do the entitlements file. Really confused. Also did a clean and removed /developer/xcode/derivedData. Any help?

Zach